# Facebook Group API, members can't retrieve data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created an app in Javascript to allow members of a facebook group (closed) to get event information.  I have gotten the app approved by facebook and added it to the group, however only admins of the group are able to retrieve the required data.  Regular members as well as moderators are unable to retrieve the events.

Is there a way of doing this that I just haven't found yet? Or is it not possible at all?

Comment: How are you retrieving the data? What permission has the user granted the app?

Comment: sorry for the late response.  currently the users have the GROUP API permission which as been approved by facebook.  The app since then has also been installed to the group, as per facebook requirements.  here is the code i'm using to get the event data from the group.                                                            FB.api(
      '/528660527534967/events',
      'GET',
      {"fields":"name,description,start_time,end_time,cover,attending_count"},
      function(response) { 
        if(response && !response.error){
        buildList(response);
        }
      }
    );